# Как просматривать исходники в Sublime Text?

Tags: python, sublime-text, pycharm

В пайчарме есть отличная фича "go to declaration", название которой само говорит за себя. В Sublime Text есть похожая штука "go to definition" но она, к сожалению, только жалкая пародия пайчармовской, потому что в пайчарме можно перейти к объявлению любой функции, класса..., что нельзя с делать в Sublime Text. Вопрос: как вы быстро передвигаетесь по коду и не только своего кода? Может есть плагины в Sublime Text или специальные программы?

Comment: Если правильно понял, то достаточно добавить директорию с исходным кодом в проект и будем вам нужный переход.

Comment: да, что то на подобии этого делает пайчарм, но в сублайме потом все довольно медленно работает, да и fuzzy поиск немножко загаживает после добавления, так что не очень хороший вариант

Comment: я на php так делал - тормозов не видел, с питоном не пробовал

Comment: Попробуйте [так](http://www.bymichaellancaster.com/blog/sublime-text-3-jump-to-definition-custom-shortcut/). Но вообще конечно стоит помнить, что SublimeText -- это всё же не IDE, а просто довольно умный редактор :)

Comment: @Alex Belyaev так я же об этой штуке в вопросе написал, все же она не всегда работает, да и не очень хорошо. У меня общий вопрос. Может кто через гитхаб смотрит, кто по папочкам кликает, хочу найти наилучший способ.

Comment: по нормальному, чтобы как в pycharm? никак. да и в принципе, не нужно, если вы зарабатываете на питоне, то ничто не мешает вам оплатить работу программистов, которые сделали для вас инструмент для зарабатывания денег. Ну или можно запилить опенсорс-проект с апишечкой и плагинами, чтобы  и индексация кода для кучи языков была и парсинг.

Comment: @strangeqargo pycharmа дла небольшких скриптов очень много, для больших проектов самое то и он своих денег стоит. Вопрос о чем ничуть легковесном и более менее быстром.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте дополнение для sublime [anaconda](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/) - в нём есть собственная реализация goto defenition - гораздо лучше встроенной